# FlexASIO terrible distortion

Tags: asio

Asio4All works great on my low-end computer with low-end Realtek integrated audio, but I want to see if I can get FlexASIO working, mainly because it can optionally *not* take exclusive control of audio output hardware (report [here](https://afewthingz.com/multiclientasio) of 20ms latency in shared mode). In exclusive mode, I get clean output with:

```
backend = "Windows WASAPI"
bufferSizeSamples = 128
[input]
device = ""
[output]
device = "[speaker output name here]"
suggestedLatencySeconds = 0.0
wasapiExclusiveMode = true  # change to false to have multiclient
```

Good start, but I want `wasapiExclusiveMode = false` for shared mode, and when I make that change, output becomes distorted beyond recognition. I've tried everything with changing values of buffer and SuggestedLatencySeconds, including removing those entries entirely from the settings file, but I keep getting the same result. Anyone have experience getting FlexASIO working well?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with audio clicks every couple seconds and sound a bit distorted. Fixed by switching to 44.1khz in DAW and windows audio device properties. Previously tried 48 and 96khz and they both had clicks for some reason.

My FlexASIO.toml:

```
backend = "Windows WASAPI"

[output]
device = "Speakers (USB Audio CODEC )"
wasapiExclusiveMode = false
wasapiAutoConvert = true
```